# Hide Values in a Table in Aggregate Levels PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to hide the text values when they are rolled up to the aggregate levels.
PowerBI automatically pulls in the first value to display.

CURRENT

[image]

The values are at the most granular level.

[image]

DESIRED OUTCOME

When rolled up to the highest level, I want to hide the values.

[image]

I've created a measure with the following DAX but it still shows the the values at the aggregrate levels.

LINK_ROLLUP = SELECTEDVALUE(LINK)

Comment: Hi, let me see you Table structure (columns, rows) as well as database related.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer this video to understand how to hide values in matrix

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcOTQcMFmhc`